# vmware workstation 12.5 lost compatibility with Mac as guest

Tags: macos, vmware-workstation

I just installed VMware workstation 12.5 on my linux host and I discovered that VMware has remove the 'Mac OS X' guest type.  Is there a way to restore it?  (am I missing a setting?)

I discovered 'unlocker208' which is supposed to patch Vmware Workstation - but I don't want to hack the vmware product...I'm hoping there is a safer way to restore MAC OS compatability

---

UPDATE: Please note that this questions asks about VMware capabilities and functionality.  Users can legitimately purchase and download OS X from the Apple store - but that is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: VMWare Workstation has never officially supported OS X on non-Apple hardware.  If you are going to violate the EULA for OS X/MacOS you will have to use the patch

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about running OS X on non-Apple hardware within a virtual machine

Comment: Also see this recent meta discussion, where the mods basically said they won't allow this type of question: http://meta.superuser.com/q/12050/144607

Comment: Actually that link says the opposite - hackintosh related questions are fair and reasonable and don't implicitly or explicitly violate and laws, etc.  Some people tend to interpret hackintosh related questions as pirating which is NOT correct.

Comment: No, re-read JourneymanGeek's answer. Even though the highest upvoted answer (my answer) suggests no ban on hackintosh questions, the one by the moderator JourneymanGeek says that they (SE) basically won't allow it even if we think it should be allowed.

Comment: I've removed reference to Mac OS X - question is only about VMware Workstation now.